# Socially tutorial (Angular2 + Meteor)

Tags: meteor, typescript, angular, angular2-meteor

URL: http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/search-sort-pagination-and-reactive-vars

While I am following the tutorial to section 12.4, the compiler always complains: 
[web.browser] client/parties-list/parties-list.ts (28, 40): Cannot find name 'ReactiveVar

Then, I type "meteor list" in my command line and I have the following:

---

```
accounts-password                1.1.4  Password support for accounts

anti:fake                        0.4.1  Random text and data generator

barbatus:ng2-meteor-accounts     0.1.6  Meteor Accounts for Angular2

barbatus:ng2-meteor-accounts-ui  0.1.3  Meteor Accounts UI for Angular2

barbatus:ng2-pagination          0.1.3  Angular2 Pagination Components

es5-shim                         4.1.14  Shims and polyfills to improve ECMAScr...

jquery                           1.11.4  Manipulate the DOM using CSS selectors

meteor-base                      1.0.1  Packages that every Meteor app needs

mobile-experience                1.0.1  Packages for a great mobile user experi...

mongo                            1.1.3  Adaptor for using MongoDB and Minimongo...

reactive-var                     1.0.6  Reactive variable

session                          1.1.1  Session variable

standard-minifiers               1.0.2  Standard minifiers used with Meteor app...

tracker                          1.0.9  Dependency tracker to allow reactive ca...

urigo:angular2-meteor            0.4.4  Angular2 and Meteor integration
```

---

The reactive-var is clearly installed. But why the compiler still complain cannot find 'ReactiveVar'?

Comment: How should the link to the tutorial help? Probably you have made some mistake. How would anyone find out using that link. Please add the code to your question that allows to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your typings are referenced correctly and are up to date.
I am using Meteor 1.2.1 and ionic2-meteor, so I have a typings folder.

Make sure you have typings NPM module installed.

```
npm install typings -g
```

And then install the typings for meteor

```
  typings install meteor --ambient

  typings install es6-promise --ambient

  typings install es6-shim --ambient
```

Include the main.d.ts file in your tsconfig.json

```
"typings": [
      "typings/ionic2-meteor/ionic-framework/ionic.d.ts",
      "typings/ionic2-meteor/ionic2-meteor.d.ts",
      "typings/angular2-meteor/angular2-meteor.d.ts",
      "typings/main.d.ts"
    ]
```

Make sure the meteor.d.ts files installed contain the following:

```
declare var ReactiveVar: ReactiveVarStatic;
interface ReactiveVarStatic {
    new<T>(initialValue: T, equalsFunc?: Function): ReactiveVar<T>;
}
interface ReactiveVar<T> {
    get(): T;
    set(newValue: T): void;
}
```

In my case I had to update my meteor.d.ts files (main and browser) because they did not contain the ReactiveVar declaration and interface.